# Golang: Command Prompt

Tags: go, prompt

I am writing a personal tool which gives me a prompt and lets me execute useful commands. Like bash but its not a shell program

I want an input prompt like Bash

If you enter nothing, just print a new line and scan for input again
If you enter the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>, terminate the program

It should be like this

```
[user@computer ~]$ go build
[user@computer ~]$ ./myapp
$
$ command
   .. do command
$ (Ctrl + D hotkey)
[user@computer ~]$
```

I tried using Scanln but it didn't accept spaces which was a huge problem

EDIT: here is what I implemented

```
func main() {
    var input string 
    fmt.Println(banners.Gecko1)
    fmt.Print("$ ")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Here is the console:

```
[user@pc MyTool]$ go build
[user@pc MyTool]$ ./MyTool

-----ENTER COMMANDS 
$ term1 term2 term3 term4 term5
[user@pc MyTool]$ erm2 term3 term4 term5
bash: erm2: command not found
[user@pc MyTool]$
```

as you can see, everything after term1 is ignored and somehow passed to bash...

Comment: Can you post a more specific example of an input you want to accept and what you tried with Scanln? I'm reading the docs and I think Scanln can still work for you but I want to know exactly what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't accept spaces"? You may want to just read the input lines directly rather than dealing with `Scanln`. If you really want it to be like a shell prompt, you will need to use or implement a readline library.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's how scanln is supposed to work. The docs state that it "scans text from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments." Alternatively, use the bufio package if you want to read one line at a time. You can refer to the sample code below:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input_reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Print("$ ")
        line, _ := input_reader.ReadString('\n')
        line = strings.Replace(line, "\n", "", -1)
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```